# SSIS ODBC Orign does not save the SQL Command

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc

My SQL Command does not save on the ODBC orign and the fields doesnt show on the columns menu, but the data shows on the visualization button:

[image]

If i click on the columns menu:

[image]

It's a ODBC Connection on a mysql database.

I've tryed to set the sql command via propertys and the mapping works, but when i execute the data flow, i recive a message with success but the data does not go to the destination.

Edit: My version of the Mysql database is 5.6.20. I'm testing multiple odbc drivers to see if is here the problem